# Same as shipping checkbox in admin is not showing

Tags: commerce

While creating an order from Drupal admin section, "Same as shipping" checkbox is not showing, but for normal checkout it is showing.

How do I show the checkbox in the administrative page?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this checkbox is meant to copy the address from the billing address to the shipping address?

As Ryan pointed out on the frontend this will require ajax as the shipping and billing profiles could be on different steps, however on the backend they are both on the same page so all that is required is some javascript.

For example...

Add the checkbox and custom javascript to the page in a hook_form_alter:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() for commerce_order_ui_order_form.
 */
function MY_MODULE_form_commerce_order_ui_order_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  // Add the checkbox
  $form['commerce_customer_billing'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['profiles'][0]['copy_from_shipping'] = [
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('Copy address from shipping'),
    '#attributes' => ['class' => ['copy-address-from-shipping']],
  ];

  // Attach our custom js
  $form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('MY_MODULE', 'taronga') . '/js/copy-address-from-shipping.js';

}
```

And then for the javascript:

```
(function($) {

    /**
     * The Drupal behaviors to copy address from shipping to billing on admin order edit page.
     */
    Drupal.behaviors.copyShippingAddress = {
        attach: function(context) {

            // Only bind our click event handler once
            $('.copy-address-from-shipping').once(function(){

                // Bind the click event
                $('.copy-address-from-shipping').click(function () {

                    var $shipping = $('#edit-commerce-customer-shipping-und-profiles-0');
                    var $billing = $('#edit-commerce-customer-billing-und-profiles-0');

                    if($(this).is(':checked')) { // Copy values from shipping

                        // Loop over inputs & select in shipping fieldset
                        $shipping.find('input, select').each(function () {
                            // Skip any inputs without a name attribute (e.g. chosen)
                            if($(this).is('[name]')) {
                                // Get the name of this field and convert it to the billing name
                                var billing_name = $(this).attr('name').replace('shipping', 'billing');
                                var $billing_field = $billing.find('[name="' + billing_name + '"]');
                                // Make sure the billing field exists
                                if($billing_field.length) {
                                    // Replace the value
                                    $billing_field.val($(this).val());
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    }
                    else { // Clear values

                        $billing.find('input, select').each(function(){
                            $(this).val('');
                        });

                    }
                });

            });

        }
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: It's actually more than just JavaScript; it's an Ajax enabled form that interacts specifically with the checkout form to work across checkout pages and more. There's no simple way to enable it on the back end.

Comment: @RyanSzrama yes, on the front end you are right, ajax will be needed as the billing and shipping profiles could be on different steps. But on the backend they are both on the same page so just straight javascript will do the trick. I've updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to specify whether you're using Drupal 7 or Drupal 8 in your questions, as the feature sets in the Commerce modules do diverge. That said, in either case, this functionality is currently not possible. I doubt it will be added in Drupal 7 given the constraints of how the checkbox was implemented to be unique to the checkout form, but look for address book support on the back end in Commerce 2.x as soon as we resolve some tricky profile select element issues.